# In PHP, What is the execution logic difference between ternary and an If statement?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I don't know what I am missing! I have the following code

```
//does not work
$arg = (isset($_REQUEST['TEST']))? $_REQUEST['TEST'] : $_REQUEST['test'];

// While this works
if(isset($_REQUEST['TEST'])){ $arg = $_REQUEST['TEST']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['test'])){ $arg = $_REQUEST['test']; }
```

Is there a difference in how each conditional handle the above code? It reads the same to me! any explanation?

P.S

There should not be a difference ! Is there a global PHP setting that could affect this?

Comment: What do you mean `doesn't work` are you getting an error? Works as I'd expect.. https://eval.in/478642

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any functional difference between the two

```
$arg = (isset($_REQUEST['TEST']))? $_REQUEST['TEST'] : $_REQUEST['test'];
```

are you sure  $_REQUEST['test'] exists and has a value ? Because in your second statement

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['test']))
```

you are explicitly checking its value but in the first statement you are not.

Comment: right. I am saying if the Uppercase one does not exists, then default to the lower case one. It is odd now that the above comment shows a working example!

Comment: I see , only thing I could think of was that the lowercase variable was empty or was not posted thus the error

Comment: I will probably try again, I thought of asking maybe there is a difference! I use ternary operator all the time, not sure why the above happened :(